# Category implementation showing possible issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, xcode4, categories

I have a class Class, that has a private category (@interface Class (Private)).  The category has a method named "-run".

But, when XCode is showing that [classInstance run]; "may nto respond to -run".  I'm not sure why this is.  The method runs fine, and is declared in the same .m file as the actual class. Right above the actual class implementation.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my entire .m file.  I know it's extending NSArray at the moment, but I made it that way to show the example without any other .h dependency.

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@implementation NSArray (Private)

-(void)runMethod {}

@end

@implementation NSArray

- (void)letsPlay {
    [self runMethod]; // says -runMethod might be missing
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you post the implementation file? (at least the key parts of it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the compiler sees the declaration of the method `run` prior to the call of the method, you will not see that error.

Usually, private categories are done like:

```
#import "M.h"
@interface M(PrivateGunk)
.... declarations here ...
@end

@implementation M
@end

@implementation M(PrivateGunk)
.... impl here ...
@end
```

Though many of us have moved to sticking the private stuff in a class extension at the top of the file, which also allows for @properties, ivars, etc....

Comment: I've done that exact thing, and it still tells me that the private methods are missing.

Comment: I think I may have found where I went wrong.  Is the @interface required, even if the private @implementation above the actual implementation?  See my edit in original post.

Comment: Huh -- I'm surprised that it compiled at all.  Muscle memory has me always coupling a category `@implementation` with a category `@interface`.  In any case-- it does appear that the compiler doesn't consider methods in an `@implementation` to be a declaration in the context of another `@implementation`.   Bug? Feature? I'll have to ponder upon that, but please file a bug, if you have a moment.